# How to dynamic change frame in CorePlot even you touch it

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I set up two CPTXYGraph plots and use UISegmentedControl to switch the UI. It works good but due to some reasons I want to have two different frame sizes, so I add the following code in one of plots:

```
CGRect hostframe=hostingView.bounds;
hostframe.origin.x+=100;
hostframe.size.width-=100;
[graph setFrame:hostframe];
```

It looks good and is actually working. However if you touch the plot UI the frame size is changed to the original. I also try to add the above code to the AxisDemo of CorePlotExamples, but still get the same result. Since I would like to have PointingDeviceDraggedEvent capability in the future, I has to find a solution for it.

Is there any way to do it? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after several experiments I found a simplest solution:

```
graph.paddingLeft -= 100.0;
```

Now I can switch the UIs and change the frame size automatically without any problem. And also thanks for Eric's info.

Answer (score 0):

The Core Plot hosting view always keeps the graph sized to fill its `bounds`. Instead of resizing the graph, resize the hosting view.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Yes, actually I had tried to resize the hosting view (i.e.CPTGraphHostingView), but it didn't have any change. Do I have to call anything to refresh the UI?

Comment: How are you positioning the hosting view in its parent? If using auto layout, you'll need to adjust the constraints.

Comment: I don't use auto layout since my UI is not rotatable. Just have a fixed UI to place those two CPTXYGraph plots in the screen.